# How to make an NSTextView layer backed?

Tags: swift, macos, layer, appkit, nstextview

How can you make an NSTextView layer backed? 
I know you can make an NSView layer backed by setting the NSView.wantsLayer property to true.
When I do this on an NSTextView the text it normally displays is not visible.

This is my swift (playground) code:

```
import Cocoa
import QuartzCore

let tv = NSTextView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
tv.string = "Hello world."
tv.wantsLayer = true
```

The property `tv.layer` returns an NSTextViewBackingLayer, which sounds at least something related to displaying text.

What is going wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: It works in a Cocoa project. Don't know why it doesn't work in Playground

Comment: Do you use the same code in the Cocoa project? Does the text view have a layer before `tv.wantsLayer = true`?

Comment: I wanted to add a mask to the `NSTextView.layer.mask` property, to create a truncating fade out effect on the end of the string.
I use the same code in a cocoa project, where it is also not working. `tv.layer` returns nil before `tv.wantsLayer = true`.

Comment: @CodeDifferent it doesn't work in a Cocoa project. Add a text view to a XIB/storyboard and check the Core Animation Layer checkbox. The width of the frame is 0.0 in the nib. Any ideas?

Comment: `tv.layer` returned also all kinds of zero sized frames and bounds. Before you set `tv.wantsLayer = true` the `tv.frame` and
`tv.bounds` properties return both a correct size of 100x50. After setting `tv.wantsLayer = true` the properties are changed to zeros. 

So if we try to set the correct sizes again in combination with a `tv.layerContentsRedrawPolicy` set to the default value `NSView.LayerContentsRedrawPolicy.duringViewResize`, then `tv.layer.contents` will be updated when we change these geometry properties.

Comment: I had to set both `tv.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50)` and `tv.minSize = NSSize(width: 100, height: 50)`. 
After this a correct layer is displayed. This is quite cumbersome and I'm not sure why this works. It seems like something goes wrong when enabling layer support.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a CALayer to a NSTextField screws up the frame, you have to set those values as the new CALayer sets them to 0,0,0,0.